# How to access Spring Bean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spring, freemarker, spring-bean

I can access Spring Bean in FreeMarker Template (FTL) this way:

String:
`'${myBean.myInfo.stringValue}'`

Map: `<#list myBean.myMap?values as value>`

How to access these in JavaScript?

Comment: FreeMarker runs on the server, while JavaScript runs on the client. The Internet is between them. You have to explicitly transmit data between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: either do as @Poinky described or simply hardcode (eg JSON encode it) the data using FTL into the webpage so that javascript can find it and read it